# How to remove a Firestore listener in a non-activity class (repository class) Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code that gets data from Cloud Firestore:

```
coll_table.get().addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                MyClass obj = document.toObject(MyClass.class);
                System.out.println(obj.showDetails());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When I use it in my activity class, it works fine since I can pass **`this`** to the `addOnCompleteListener()` function but when I move this code in a non-activity (Repository) class, it doesn't work. I read in Android docs that is not correct to use a context object in a ViewModel or in a Repository class, so how can I remove the listener in this situation?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to pass `this` at all.  There is an overload of [addOnCompleteListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#addOnCompleteListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener%3CTResult%3E)) that just accepts the listener, so use that instead.

For more details with respect to dealing with listeners, you might want to look at the source code of this project to see one way to handle Firestore and Realtime Database listener with Android architecture components.  Similar patterns could be applied to the result of tasks.  https://github.com/CodingDoug/firebase-jetpack

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm now a little confused. So you say that because I use `coll_table.get()` there is no listener that has to be removed and I can simply use `addOnCompleteListener` without `this`? Or if is not the case, you say that once I got the data from `LiveData`, I can remove the listener, is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up get() with persistent onSnapshot listeners that must be removed.  Edited.

Comment: Just bear in mind that if your activity goes away after a listener is added to a task, the task might still complete and try to do something with the data.  You might want to be mindful of that case.

Comment: One more small clarification please. In case of authentication, should I remove the listener? `auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, ...)` or it is enough to use the other function without it?